# IONIC Android Navigation bar overlaps app screen

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

Android soft navigation bar on certain phones overlaps the page of the app.
[image]

I previously had a similar problem with the status bar (top bar on android), which was solved by adding a plugin and adding a line of code in my `app.component.js`

`this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);`

the available solution to hide the navigation bar after adding the `cordova-plugin-navigationbar`.

```
import { NavigationBar } from '@ionic-native/navigation-bar/ngx';

constructor(private navigationBar: NavigationBar) { }

...

let autoHide: boolean = true;
this.navigationBar.setUp(autoHide);
```

is there any way I can stop the overlapping?

Solution which worked for me

I was using statusbar plugin, while using the plugin make sure in your `config.xml` file
`<preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="false" />`
we have resizeOnFullscreen to false. and it should solve it.

Comment: I encountered the issue on Android 13. From your description, it's not very clear to me whether you solved the issue somehow, or it still persists. Could you clarify? I'm also looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: I have solved this issue, in config.xml `<preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="false" />` when using the status bar plugin along side. I had spent a lot of time finding a solution but this worked for me.

Comment: However, it only works consistently if I do the following after the app is initialized:
1. this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
2. wait (timeout)
3. this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);

Comment: yes, you'll need to have `this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);`  with the above-suggested solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

## Ionic >= 6

The error happen because of the `StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({ overlay: true })` logic.

### Avoid using `setOverlaysWebView`

Con: The content wont adapt himself to the keyboard when it open

```
// app.component.ts
StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({ overlay: false }) // Default value, shall be safely removed
```

### Timeout

Con: Dirty workaround, may not work *(To be tested)*

```js
// app.component.ts
setTimeout(() => {
  StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({ overlay: true })
}, 100)
```

## Ionic <= 5

### Avoid using `overlaysWebView`

Con: The content wont adapt himself to the keyboard when it open

```xml
// config.xml
<preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="false" />
```

```js
// app.component.ts
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

## Related issue

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6423